# Free SQL Query generator tool for oracle database?

Tags: oracle, devtools

Do you use any free tool to generate query for oracle database.
Tool that autocomplete and suggests the table names and column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html) has auto-complete and such.

Written and maintained by Oracle themselves.  It is written in java though, and can be quite slow to respond after being minimized for a while (not that java is the cause, cough, cough).

Answer (score 0):

[Henplus](http://henplus.sourceforge.net/) includes auto-complete features; I haven't tried it with Oracle, but I would be surprised if it doesn't work in that context. Unfortunately, the project seems to have stalled.